# Can we separate out privileges from reputation?

Tags: feature-request, privileges

My question revolves around the fact that reputation is an ambiguous term that doesn't allow for things like: infamous people with correct answers.

I understand that we want to keep things civil, however, we are also creating a huge disincentive to getting those people who know things to share things without sparing their "reputation".  This would allow for the posting of questions or answers that should be taken down by moderators anyway, without using reputation dings or downvotes on answers as a mechanism to prevent future ability to participate in comments and answers.  If I consistently answer questions that get novel viewpoints on stackoverflow, who cares that they're wrong?  The argument, as the Greeks used it, often proves more useful than the initially "wrong" viewpoint. 
In any case, the downvotes will show people's opinion on anyone else's "truth", and the viewer decides which answer has more veracity.  Isn't that the point: surface as many potential answers, rank and stack them by upvotes, while rewarding EVERYONE that was involved, regardless of whether we agree with their answers?

If I answer 100 questions on python, and only one garners an upvote, but that ONE answer unlocked understanding that outweighs the other 99 misses, isn't this BETTER than what we have now?  As it stands, you are tying correctness to political correctness, which I don't care about when I want just the correct part of any answer.

If reputation is just a number, aren't we making a pre-optimization that weeds out avenues we initially think are wrong, but lead to rightness?  And, as a forum, don't we want argument by definition?  Stack exchange has become a place where ad hominem attacks of 'tone policing' are rampant, IMO, and this is BY DESIGN.  But stating this makes people discount the entire truth in my question, and THAT is the problem.  Look past my views, and look at my logic.

I desire a feature that separates out reputation from the privileges of participation.  I should be able to logically show that an answer is wrong, regardless of whether my "tone" is liked.  And that fact is being neglected in the entirety of this supposed "forum of forums".

To put yet another way: As my reputation is too low, I can't even make a feature request and instead have to use my superior logic to backdoor it through the form of a valid question.  This then begs the question: why do you lock feature-requests away from everyone, when everyone can just vote on the best ideas? Not just ideas from people you like?!?

Comment: _"infamous people with correct answers."_ What makes them _infamous_ can you take care to elaborate about this?

Comment: "I should be able to logically show that an answer is wrong, regardless of whether my "tone" is liked." that's just the way it works in real life as well. *C'est le ton qui fait la musique!*

Comment: I think you mean 'unknown', not 'infamous'... and that's not likely to happen. On SE, high-rep users don't receive more visibility, unless you count cases of misuse where somebody scrolls through an author's profile upvoting all their posts. A user with several correct answers will definitely gain reputation, because the community will see their answers and vote on them even if the author's reputation is initially low. Also, you can always propose feature requests: even this post is tagged (perhaps improperly) with 'feature request' (though you can't always vote on other requests).

Comment: If you think an answer is wrong then why don't you add your own correct answer?

Comment: I could post 500 answers to questions on Superuser.  If just one of those answers, was written in such a way, I could easily deceive somebody into formatting their system without any sort of warning.  Wouldn't you agree that if I gave somebody an answer that did that, the answer should be deleted and/or the answer should recieve downvotes?

Answer (score 7):

> Isn't that the point: surface as many potential answers, rank and stack them by upvotes, while rewarding EVERYONE that was involved, regardless of whether we agree with their answers?

... No, it's not.

"The point" is to create a database of useful knowledge. That requires a way of sifting useful information from less useful information. We incentivize the creation of useful information via the reputation system, in the hope that it will encourage those who can provide useful information consistently to continue to do so.

We also use the reputation system to dis-incentivize participation from those who frequently create useless information.

The voting system is a good tool for figuring out which answers are better. But having bad answers *at all* is (usually) not a good thing, just as having bad questions is not good. We don't want to have answers just to *have them*; we want all answers to be good, just like all questions.

The voting system is best used as a failsafe for answers that are accidentally wrong, or to allow multiple *good* answers to be rated for relative quality. It isn't there to allow people to just post whatever they want on every question until they manage to get one right.

The only case where bad answers might be useful is as an example of what *not to do*. For new programmers especially, seeing a heavily downvoted bad idea that they commonly see elsewhere could divert them away from popular anti-patterns.

But even then, instructively-bad answers are usually not well categorized by our system. We categorize information by problems to be solved. And while some instructively-bad answers are bad because they represent bad solutions to that problem, others get that way by employing popular anti-patterns. Well, those usually are not specific to the problem defined by the question. Basically, users will not run into them when they *need* them; they'll see them at random.

So even in the case of instructively-bad answers, their benefit to the site is dubious.

> If I answer 100 questions on python, and only one garners an upvote, but that ONE answer unlocked understanding that outweighs the other 99 misses, isn't this BETTER than what we have now?

Who decides how much that one answer "weighs" relative to the others?

Furthermore, your answers are not unique. There are other people on the site who can almost certainly provide the same information you could. So if you have two people, and one of them has a correct:incorrect ratio of 1:99 and the other has a correct:incorrect ratio of 99:1... which one is doing the better job on the site?

If you are frequently posting bad answers... we don't really need your answers here. Shotgun answering is not helpful.

> And, as a forum, don't we want argument by definition?

Oh, there's your problem. Stack Exchange *is not a forum*.

We do not want argument, period. We want questions and answers. That's why we organize our site by questions which have answers. That's why comments are limited to 600 characters, while questions and answers have very high limits. That's why comments require reputation before you can post them, while answers can be posted with 1 rep.

We don't want discussion; we want questions and answers.

> I desire a feature that separates out reputation from the privileges of participation. I should be able to logically show that an answer is wrong, regardless of whether my "tone" is liked.

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about here. This all seems exceedingly confused.

If you find that an answer is wrong, you can already do this now. You can post a comment on the answer if you want to get the person to change it. Or you can post a competing answer that provides the correct answer to the question, while simultaneously explaining why the other answer is wrong.

I don't know where "tone" gets into this. Yes, if you violate our posting guidelines, your answer will be flagged as appropriate to your violations. We're not going to change that just for you. But so long as you're not being confrontational and so long as you're addressing the question itself in your answer, your "tone" is irrelevant.

> As my reputation is too low, I can't even make a feature request and instead have to use my superior logic to backdoor it through the form of a valid question.

Posting a question on MSE with the tag [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is called "making a feature request". So your "superior logic" has nothing to do with this.